# Issues with Physics.CheckSphere and LayerMask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on my first simulation concept, an attempt at spreading trees that are eventually eaten by creatures.
I've got the basics down, I think (probably not) but I'm having issues with Physics.CheckSphere.

The process of my code is to:

1. Use an empty container to check if there is a nearby plant. No plant? Spawn a plant, then move to a new location.
2. If there is already a plant here, move to a nearby location with no pre-existing plants.
   Same process, spawn a plant, then set new destination.

The issue I'm having is firstly, the check sphere is not detecting the plant once it is spawned.

Here's my (Updated) code. The main issue is in relation to a CheckSphere and the LayerMask.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class SpawnPlant : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject plantPrefab;
    public NavMeshAgent plantSpawner;

    public float minAdjacentPlantRange;
    public float movePointRange;

    bool movePointSet = false, atMovePoint, plantAdjacent;
    public Vector3 movePoint;
    public LayerMask Plant;

    private void Awake()
    {
        plantAdjacent = Physics.CheckSphere(plantSpawner.transform.position, minAdjacentPlantRange, Plant);
        if (!plantAdjacent) atMovePoint = true;
        if (plantAdjacent) atMovePoint = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (atMovePoint) SpawnNewPlant();
        if (!atMovePoint) FindNewMovePoint();
    }

    private void FindNewMovePoint()
    {
        if (!movePointSet) FindMovePoint();
        if (movePointSet) TranformToSetPoint();
    }

    private void SpawnNewPlant()
    {
        GameObject plant = Instantiate(plantPrefab, plantSpawner.transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 359), Vector3.up));
        atMovePoint = false;
    }


    private void FindMovePoint()
    {
        while(movePointSet == false)
        {
            float deltaZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-movePointRange, movePointRange);
            float deltaX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-movePointRange, movePointRange);
            movePoint = new Vector3(plantSpawner.transform.position.x + deltaX, plantSpawner.transform.position.y, plantSpawner.transform.position.z + deltaZ);
            plantAdjacent = Physics.CheckSphere(movePoint, minAdjacentPlantRange, Plant);
            if (Physics.Raycast(movePoint, -transform.up, 2f) && !plantAdjacent)
                movePointSet = true;
        }
    }

    private void TranformToSetPoint()
    {
        plantSpawner.SetDestination(movePoint);
        
        Vector3 distanceToWalkPoint = transform.position - movePoint;
        if (distanceToWalkPoint.magnitude < 0.1)
        {
            movePointSet = false;
            atMovePoint = true;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't this C#? Why have you tagged it as C++?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! also as already stated this is `c#` not `c++`

Comment: Note that `Update` is automatically called by Unity **every frame**! And you only pick a new random position once ... what if there again already is a pant? You would probably rather go with a loop and pick random positions until you either run out of attempts or find an empty spot

Comment: So just these comments made me realize I know even less than I thought. Thank you for the fix to the tags. I've been learning C++ on the side and forgot that Unity is common run on C#. And I was completely unaware that unityscript was it's own language. I still have a lot to learn. Anyway, I'm going to try running the update function as a while loop in a void function? Sounds like the update function is part of the issue.

Comment: Updated code. It works except for the detection mechanic.

Comment: i thought this was some crazy anti-vax post

Comment: For the Physics stuff to work, you'd need Collider(s) on your GameObjects.  Just thought worth mentioning in case you haven't got them.  As read here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html

Comment: That was it. Didn't add a collider :| Thank you Rayson!